# Struggling with gravitational potential definition

Tags: gravity

The textbook for my A-Level physics course defines the gravitational potential at a point as:

The work done per unit mass to move a small object from infinity to that point.

But if Work = Force * distance,
This definition makes no sense, because to move something from A to B you can apply as small a force as you want, let go, and it will keep on going until it gets there. If you're not in a rush, you can do it with as little work as you like, so F is effectively 0.

Also, if you're moving from infinity to a finite displacement, distance d is effectively infinite.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JohnRennie That is not analogous to my situation: you are talking about moving something against a force, I am talking about moving something towards a massive body, therefore in the direction of the force due to gravity. Read the question before you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This definition makes no sense, because to move something from A to B you can apply as small a force as you want, let go, and it will keep on going until it gets there.

That would be correct if there was no gravitational force, but it is not true in the case you are talking about. If you throw some object up it won't keep going forever, it will come back, exactly because of the gravitational force, so you can't move an object away from a source of gravitational force (like the earth) with an arbitrarily small force, as you can see for yourself when lifting something from the surface of the earth.

> Also, if you're moving from infinity to a finite displacement, distance d is effectively infinite.

The distance is infinite, but there is no force infinitely far away, so the work is still finite. For gravitational force you have:

$$F \propto \frac {1}{r^2} \implies \lim_{r \to \infty}F=0$$

But if you want to be more precise, it is important to notice that $F \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ is not enough for the work to be finite, since the work in this case is:

$$W= \int_{\infty}^d F(r) \cdot dr$$

You can see that for $F(r) \propto \frac {1}{r}$ the work would be infinite, even though $\lim_{r \to \infty}F=0$. So the fact that the potential is $0$ at $\infty$ needs not only the force to go $0$ at $\infty$, but it also needs the force to go to $0$ "fast enough".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was slightly thrown off by your introduction because you appear to be talking about moving something to infinity from a point (i.e. against gravity) rather than the other way around. If you could clarify I would be grateful.

Comment: We are talking about two different works here. One is the work from the gravitational force, and the other is the work done by someone trying to overcome the gravitational force. From the integral expression you can see that the work done by the gravitational force to bring a stationary mass from infinity is the same as the work done by someone overcoming the gravitational force sending this mass to be stationary at infinity.

Comment: Just to make it clearer, when gravity brings the object from infinity it is obvious that no one needs to do work to make it happen, but that is because all the work is being done by gravity, and this is the computation used for the potential.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. So the work is the area under the graph of F against r, and F is proportional to 1/r^2, so the area under the graph (and thus work) is finite even up to r = infinity. Is that what you meant? Also, I think I get what you mean now by the force going to 0 "fast enough" because 1/r^2 goes down quicker than 1/r, but still not sure what the significance of that is.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The significance of that is to show that it is not enough for the force to go $0$ for the area under the graph to be finite. I gave the example of the $1/r$ force, which goes to $0$ at infinity, but the area under that graph would still be infinite. For the $1/r^2$ case the force decreases faster for bigger $r$ making the area under the graph finite, which is what we want to be able to define the potential this way

Comment: Whoa. You just blew my mind. Had no idea the area under 1/r was infinite. Thank you so much for all your help!